# Enquiries - Laravel website migration steps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

I got a website running with laravel framework, this website will need to migrate to public cloud VM. However, I'm not quite familiar with laravel, any suggestion and advice would be appreciated.

I already created a remote VM, and installed Nginx.

Also, I move the root folder from on-prem /var/wwwroot to the cloud /var/wwwroot as well. Moreover, the Mysql database had been imported to the cloud Mysql too (using the dumped .sql file ).

1. laravel need PHP to run, should I install php5.6 or php5.6-fpm (or both)?
2. I need to install laravel framework, do I have to install the specific version of lavavel (5.1.46)?
3. After I install the laravel, do I need to conduct any laravel command such as 
   ~#php artisan migrate ? or just put the wwwroot folder's file should be enough?

Here is more info about the on-prem VM:

~#php --version
**PHP 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)**

~#nginx -v
**nginx version: nginx/1.13.6**

~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
**Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

~# php artisan --version
**Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)**

~# mysqld --version
**mysqld  Ver 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))**

Answer (score 1):

Tony.

1. You want to use NGINX as webserver, so you need to install both packages.
2. If you install your code from git, you should install dependencies by running command:

> php composer install

3. You should create your .env-file and edit it: set up db connection params and other settings:

> cp .env.example .env

Also you should generate app key:

> php artisan key:generate

If you copied last version of your db, you don't need to run up migrations,  but I recommend you to run new migrations, to be confident that db structure wasn't changed since you make dump.

> php artisan migrate

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MasteRus. I'm nearly done, expect SSL cert. In my on-prem website nginx conf, there is no 443 section. I then found the laravel's .env APP_URL=https, therefore AppServiceProvider.php  [\URL::forceSchema('https')] will take the effects. However, I couldn't find my SSL cert location. any idea?